# Understanding Abstentions/Pass Vote

Tags: governance, voting, ballot

I can read from the docs:

"The pass vote allows a delegate to not influence a vote but still allowing it to reach quorum."

If we get the following result, in a Voting Period (Quorum = 80%):

> 60% Yes
>
> 19% No
>
> 21% Abstention/Pass

Will the Quorum be met? Would it lead to an amendment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is I believe here a slight confusion on your part in the interpretation of the word "quorum" here because as per implementation there are 2 conditions for the amendment to be accepted:

- the *voting quorum* must be met, where quorum here means the percentage of actual votes (yay + nay + pass) to the total number of possible votes (80% initially and progressively reduced in subsequent rounds)
- casted votes (yay + nay) must give a *super majority* to yes. This one is always fixed at 80%

So the documentation and code indicate that "pass" votes count for 1) but not for 2)

That being said the example your provide does *not* allow to answer the first question because you did not provide the actual number of yes,no,pass votes so we cannot assess whether the quorum was met (condition 1) but as Arthur pointed out the *supermajority* was not met (condition 2) so the amendment would not pass.

Look here for more details

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/357

Answer (score 4):

No, 60% / (60% + 19%) ≈ 76% < 80%